# jQuery AJAX fires early with current page data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've been reading about jQuery's deferred methods and am trying to implement them on an AJAX call.

What I'm attempting is to listen for a click on an element (`.slideLink`), grab the contents of the corresponding href value, and then either log the results or log an error, depending on the outcome.

The problem is, the contents of the *current* page are logged as soon as the page loads. Clicking on `.slideLink` does nothing at all.

This is what I have so far:

```
function getDetails(val){
    return jQ.get(val);
};

// click handler
jQ('#slides').on('click', '.slideLink', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var addy = jQ(this).attr("href");
    getDetails(addy);
});

jQ.when( getDetails() )
    .done(function(results) {
        console.log(results);
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log( 'It doesn\'t work... :(' );
    });
```

Clearly I misunderstand a fundamental principle, but I'm drawing blanks via google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are firing getDetails() as soon as the page loads. Also, each time you execute getDetails() a separate request is fired and a new deferred is returned. Try this:

```
function getDetails(val){
    return jQ.get(val);
}

// click handler
jQ('#slides').on('click', '.slideLink', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var addy = jQ(this).attr("href");
    getDetails(addy).done(function(results) {
        console.log(results);
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log( 'It doesn\'t work... :(' );
    });;
});
```

Comment: Thank you - that's perfect! Am I right in guessing that the `when()` event triggered `getDetails` on page load?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [(from what I read in the docs)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) that `jQ.when( getDetails() )` is going to run your function right from when the page loads.

It might be better to use `ajax()` over `get()` that way you can utilize the `done` and the `fail` callback properties.

```
function getDetails( val ) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: val,
        data: (yourdata),
        success : function(){},
        error : function(){}
    })
}
```

Also, you can call the `click()` method directly on `.slideLink` if you wanted to.

```
jQ('.slideLink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var addy = jQ(this).attr("href");
    getDetails(addy);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip re: `ajax()` - I've not come across anything mentioning it would be more suitable before.

Comment: `get()` definitely has the callbacks options available, but the `ajax()` method has them built right in without chaining. `get()` is just a `GET` specific implementation of the `ajax()` method.

Comment: Ideally I'd like to keep the callbacks separate, as the logic will likely be used elsewhere. Can I still do this with `ajax()`?

Comment: Check out the [`context` portion here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) under the settings list.